# How to reverse cmap for select rows in table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to style rows in a table created from data in a csv file. I'm using Jupyter Notebook to run my python code. The data in my csv file is as follows:

```
[[' ', 'VZ', 'T', 'TMUS'],
['Current Ratio', 1.4, .8, 1.1],
['Quick Ratio', 1.3, .8, 1.0],
['Debt to Equity', 1.9, .97, 1.17],
['LT Debt to Equity', 1.82, .95, 1.09],
['ROA', 6.1, 2.0, 1.8],
['ROI', 10.9, 1.7, 4.1],
['Gross Margin', 59.5, 52.7, 59.6],
['Oper. Margin', 19.1, 13.0, 9.7],
['Profit Margin', 14.1, 6.3, 4.5]]
```

[image: csv file]

The csv is saved to my desktop, I'm reading it in using pandas read_csv:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/broderickbonelli/Desktop/test.csv', index_col=" ")
```

My goal is to correctly color code the table with the 'RdYlGn' color map. I'm using .style.background_gradient().

```
data = data.style.background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn')

display(data)
```

This applies the color map to the entire table. The issue I'm coming across is various rows (the debt to equity rows) need a reversed color map while keeping the rest of the table the same/unaltered.

I now need to reverse the color map for only the "Debt to Equity" and "LT Debt to Equity" rows as high values should be red and low values green. I am able to target the rows as subsets and apply the reversed cmap 'RdYlGn_r' but now the gradient isn't applying properly as all columns are the same color.

The code I tried is:

```
data = data.style.background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn').set_precision(2).background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn_r',  subset=(data.index[2], data.columns)).background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn_r', subset=(data.index[3], data.columns))

display(data)
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQMpA.png)

I'm not sure why the gradient isn't applying correctly for the debt-to-equity rows, but it is when I apply to the whole table. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to import a color map object from matplotlib and use the reversed method and then supply the reversed color map to the `cmap` argument:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap

In pandas 1.3.0 (upcoming release) there is a new keyword argument `gmap` which allows you to supply your own values for the gradient map, in this case a quick reversal would be applied if your did: `df.style.background_gradient(cmap="RdYlGn", gmap=-df)`

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah the reversed method _r is what I used for index[2] and index[3], however it is not applying the gradient correctly as it did when I applied to all rows using:    background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn')